# Linux application crashes, no core dump while "ulimit -c unlimited" and "/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern" are set

Tags: linux, dump

Folks, my server written in C++ periodically crashes but produces no core dump at all.

Core dumps are produced for sure: "ulimit -c" and "/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern" are set properly.

The weird thing is that I tried to kill the server manually for several times using "kill -s SIGSEGV $pid" and the cores *were* produced all times.

Is there any explanation and solution for such a strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my application is killed by oom-killer...now I have to investigate why this happens :(

Answer (score 2):

It may be receiving a signal that doesn't dump core by default. See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: Well, in my signal handler I only allow USR1 and USR2 not to produce the core file, all other signals produce the core for sure. Furthermore all signals are logged - there are no signals at all when the server crashes...